# What is the proper name for a Quantile Bar Chart?

Tags: data-visualization, terminology, quantiles

What is the proper name for a **Bar Chart** plotting quantiles (like percentiles) in abscissa (X-axis) and a corresponding continuous variable in ordinate (Y-axis)? For example, if the chart is based on percentiles (100 bars), the height of the 25th bar should depict the first quartile.

I am looking for what could be a universally-accepted name in order to support the development of this [unified typology of statistical variables](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mzyU2Pl2Ls1S_hUbx3Y6nmeEAhqrr7GhxIF_5RfnI0A/edit#gid=1589567667) and its related set of [canonical univariate plots](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mzyU2Pl2Ls1S_hUbx3Y6nmeEAhqrr7GhxIF_5RfnI0A/edit#gid=1714237498).

Comment: I notice you are asking a series of "proper name" questions. Could you please, then, explain what you mean by a "proper name," state why you expect there might be a universally accepted such name, and indicate why knowing it might be of interest?

Comment: Great point! Just added some context.